# Crear un campo nuevo dentro de una tabla e introducirle el valor de otro pero cogiendo el valor de una fila siguiente

Tags: python, pandas

Os comento: He hecho anteriormente una pregunta "Crear un campo nuevo dentro de una tabla e introducirle el valor de otro pero cogiendo el valor de una fila anterior" y ya la he solucionado. 
Ahora me surge otro problema y es que quiero hacer lo mismo pero cogiendo el valor de la fila siguiente.
Aquí os pongo el código que utilice en mi pregunta anterior a ver si me podrías decir como coger los valores de la fila siguiente.

```html
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,2],
                   'Fecha' : ['2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2009-02-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-04-01','2009-04-01','2009-04-01'],
                   'Cierre' : [25.5,26.04,88.8,26.8,24.8,27.5,23.05,27.8,30.20]})

NumIntervalo =2 # Me he creado una variable para poner el número de intervalo que quiero mostrar. Así sólo con cambiar el valor aquí no tendré que modificar el procedimiento.

def Cierre1(df,NumIntervalo):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df ['Cierre1'] = ord_df['Cierre'].shift(NumIntervalo)
    idx = ord_df.iloc[NumIntervalo:]['IdActivo'].values != ord_df.iloc[:len(ord_df) - NumIntervalo]['IdActivo'].values
    for i in range(NumIntervalo):
        idx = np.append([False], idx)


    ord_df.loc[idx, 'Cierre1'] = np.nan
    print(ord_df)

Cierre1(df,NumIntervalo)
```

He intentado poner en negativo el valor NumIntervalo dentro del procedimiento pero no me sale los resultados que quiero. 
Os pongo una imagen de como quisiera que aparecieran los datos correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esperando vuestra ayuda me despido atentamente.

Charo

Answer (score 1):

Ya he resuelto mi problema así que aquí os pongo el resultado final por si a alguien le interesa.
Este el código que tengo al final:

```html
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,2],
                   'Fecha' : ['2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2009-02-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-03-01','2009-04-01','2009-04-01','2009-04-01'],
                   'Cierre' : [25.5,26.04,88.8,26.8,24.8,27.5,23.05,27.8,30.20]})

NumIntervalo = 2 # Me he creado una variable para poner el número de intervalo que quiero mostrar. Así sólo con cambiar el valor aquí no tendré que modificar el procedimiento.

def Cierre1(df,NumIntervalo):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df ['Cierre1'] = ord_df['Cierre'].shift(-NumIntervalo)
    idx = ord_df.iloc[NumIntervalo:]['IdActivo'].values != ord_df.iloc[:len(ord_df) -NumIntervalo]['IdActivo'].values
    ord_df.loc[idx, 'Cierre1'] = np.nan
    print(ord_df)

Cierre1(df,NumIntervalo)
```

Aquí os pongo una imagen con el resultado como lo queria. Si copias el código en vuestro programa y modificais la variable NumIntervalo vereis que funciona bien con otros números que le pongais.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo a todos.

Charo.